# RowLoaded event - can't modify cell content

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

During development with Devexpress, we've encountered the use of a `InstantFeedbackSource`. Using the `Row_Loaded`, we would like to adjust values of certain rows. Yet the CellContent isn't changed.

**Testsolution:**

*GetQueryable-Method of my datasource:*

```
    private void linqInstantFeedbackSource1_GetQueryable_1(object sender, GetQueryableEventArgs e)
    {
        e.QueryableSource = _testObjects.AsQueryable();
        gridView2.RefreshData();
        gridControl2.RefreshDataSource();
    }
```

*My Row-loaded event*

```
    private void gridView2_RowLoaded(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowEventArgs e)

         gridView2.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridView2.Columns["RandomGuid4"], "lalalala");
    }
```

*Information:*

`gridView2.Columns["RandomGuid4"]` is not null and refers to the correct-column.

`e.RowHandle` Refers to the correct Linenumber

**Goal:**

I want to achieve the following behavior:
At runtime i want to fill the gird with records. When adding the rows i want to check the row for certain values. When a certain value occurs then several another cells should be filled with combobox, hyperlinks,...

The advised way by devexpress is the event `CustomCellEdit`. But that event is highly unreliable. We're experiencing issues (exceptions from within the control). I've submitted several tickets so far but no response. So we're searching an alternative.

Could someone point out what i'm exactly missing/doing wrong here?

Thank you for your time.

**Note:** I've tried the use of `RefreshData` in my `RowLoaded-Event` but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: It is not possible to update cell values in a straightforward way. In Instant Feeback mode the GridView is read-only. What your actual goal is? Probably, your task has a more elegant solution.

Comment: I've updated the question with my actual goal.